# Powerpoint Shapes.AddOLEObject ComException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, com, vsto, powerpoint

I'm new to implementing Powerpoint AddIns and I want to add a custom control/class library to a powerpoint shape using AddOleObject. To manage this I searched for a ActiveX Example on the web and found and used the code that can be found here: http://www.mycsharp.de/wbb2/thread.php?threadid=3791
After adding the code to my project I'm always ending up in a ComException.

[image: ComException]

The Code I call from a Button Click event is:

PowerPoint.Shape myShapeObject = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5rjh.png).Shapes.AddOLEObject(10, 10, curDocument.PageSetup.SlideWidth, curDocument.PageSetup.SlideHeight, "ActiveXExample.All");

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and Office 2010

Comment: I've helped you inline the image, but please show **your** code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to Add the AddOleObject call:

PowerPoint.Shape myObject = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides[1].Shapes.AddOLEObject(10, 10, curDocument.PageSetup.SlideWidth, curDocument.PageSetup.SlideHeight, "ActiveXExample.All");